# Why the PHP SOAP session is not persistent?

Tags: php, soap

I defined a SOAP Server in the following way.

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
ini_set('session.auto_start', 0); 
global $config_dir;     
session_start();

$server = new SoapServer("xxxx.wsdl");      
$server->setClass('import');
$server->setPersistence(SOAP_PERSISTENCE_SESSION);
$server->handle();
```

When I connect it with a SoapClient and calling the public functions, the session seems not persistent. I set a private variable on a first call but this variable looses its value on the second call....

```
$client = new SoapClient('xxxx.wsdl', array('trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 1));

//The First call. I set the fromdb private variable to "nostran"
$client->setFromdb("nostran");  

//The second call. Here I need the fromdb but it has not any value....
$b = $client->setIrodak_id("1234");
```

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: check if there's indeed data in the session by the time of the second call.

Comment: @Artefacto: No, nothing there. I have four calls. Thew first two has nothing in the $_Session neither in the $_REQUEST. But in the 3. and 4. call I have serializable data in the $_REQUEST. And something in the $_SESSION, too. I got there a _bogus_session_name ....

Answer (score 2):

`_bogus_session_name` seems to be the key in the session array that soap extension uses (see the [source](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/soap/soap.c?revision=300317&view=markup#l1768)).

The usual advice on objects stored in the session apply: make sure the class definition is available before calling session_start or that you have an autoload handler set before calling `handle`.

Answer (score 0):

The SOAP library in PHP does not keep cookies between requests per default. You need to manually fetch them with getLastResponseHeaders() and set them with __setCookie().

Answer (score 0):

**First** you can try to always set the SoapHeader like this:

```
$header = new SoapHeader('{NAMESPACE__YOU_CAN_FIND_IT_IN_YOUR_WSDL__TARGETNAMESPACE}', 'SessionPersistenceHeader');

$client = new SoapClient('xxxx.wsdl', array('trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 1));

$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

The SoapHeader second parameter is chosen freely and the third parameter is optional and could be empty to solve this problem. Just add an empty header.

...and **second** you shouldn't make a `session_start()` before initializing your Server.

...and **third** try to not set your php.ini-settings on runtime but in your php.ini itself.

Hint: When you use Zend/Soap/Client.php from Zend Framework 2 the SoapHeader will be always set. That solves it for me.

TESTs: The best way to test your SoapServer on `SOAP_PERSISTENCE_SESSIONs` is to may a class Variable, a setter and a getter for it.

Here the example-class:

```
<?php

class soaptest {

    /**
     * var
     *
     * @var int
     * @access private
     */
    private $_var = 0;

    /**
     * setVar
     *
     * @param int $value
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    public function setVar($value) {
        $this->_var = $value;
    }

    /**
     * getVar
     *
     * @access public
     * @return int
     */
    public function getVar() {
        return $this->_var;
    }

}

?>
```

and than in your TestClient:

```
<?php

    // [...]

    $value = 123;
    $client->setVar($value);
    $result = $client->getVar();

    if ($value == $result) {
        echo 'SoapAPI is session persistent.';
    } else {
        echo 'SoapAPI is NOT session persistent.';
    }
?>
```